# How to read parts of a formatted text?

Tags: c, windows

It might be a simple question, but I can't figure it out.
I have a file, which contains a lot of text. This text is somehow formatted. The format is
`<![LOG["The text to display in the log."]LOG]!><time="12:48:39.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="0" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">`

From this line I want to get as a result:
- `The text to display in the log.`
- `12:48:39.0+120`
- `9-14-2015`
- `mycomponent`
- `"" (empty)`
- `0`
- `0`
- `myfile.cpp`

Any of the required values may be empty.
Is there a simple way, how I could get them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sscanf` may be . Or tokenize the string .

Comment: `sscanf` isn't the best sinc, the first string can contains spaces, and sscanf reads until the first space. If the first part wouldn't be present it could work, but it is there.

Comment: If that is some kind of XML, you might try a library. Anyway, the question is too broad.

Comment: What @Olaf said. We're not a code writing service, so asking a precise question is a must.

Comment: @Olaf: no it is not an XML. SCCM creates the logfiles in this format, and has its own logfile reading tool, which interprets this format

Comment: @MarcusMüller: AFAIK I didn't asked you to write me to the code. I was asking for Ideas.....

Comment: @kampi  It could work if you use it nicely . But as I said "maybe" .

Comment: "*the first string can contains spaces, and sscanf reads until the first space*" -- Do you mean that "*`The text to display in the log.`*" may contain spaces?  And it is the format specifiers used that matter. But `sscanf` doesn't seem right for this. Use `getchar();` in a loop.

Comment: If you *really* want to write this in C, you will want to use a [regular expression library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions).  Otherwise, this is an ideal task for Perl.  If nothing else, you can write a short Perl script that strips out the text you want and format it in a way that's easier for your C code to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the POSIX regex library available, here's one approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <regex.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  const char *text = "<![LOG[\"The text to display in the log.\"]LOG]!>"
                     "<time=\"12:48:39.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" "
                     "component=\"mycomponent\" context=\"\" type=\"0\" "
                     "thread=\"0\" file=\"myfile.cpp\">";

  /**
   * [ and ] are special characters in regular expressions and must be
   * escaped, but we must also escape the \ and " characters in string
   * literals.
   *
   * The *actual* regular expression would be
   *
   *    <!\[LOG\["(.*)"\]LOG\]!><time="(.*)" *date="(.*)" etc.
   *
   */
  const char *ptn="<!\\[LOG\\[\"(.*)\"\\]LOG\\]!>"                       
                  "<time=\"(.*)\" *date=\"(.*)\" *component=\"(.*)\" *"
                  "context=\"(.*)\" *type=\"(.*)\" *thread=\"(.*)\" *"
                  "file=\"(.*)\">";

  /**
   * "Compile" the regular expression; REG_EXTENDED means we're using
   * extended regular expression syntax (so we don't need to escape
   * opening and closing parens, among other things).  By default, 
   * we try to match subexpressions specified in parentheses.
   */
  regex_t regex;
  if ( regcomp( &regex, ptn, REG_EXTENDED ) != 0 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "regcomp failed on %s\n", ptn );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  fprintf( stdout, "number of subexpressions: %zu\n", regex.re_nsub );
  size_t matchCount=regex.re_nsub + 1;
  regmatch_t pmatch[matchCount];

  int ret = 0;
  /**
   * Try to match the input string.  matchCount specifies the *maximum*
   * number of expressions we expect to match (main string plus any  
   * subexpressions).  pmatch will contain the metadata for each expression
   * match (start and end indices in the overall string, basically).  
   */
  if ( (ret = regexec( &regex, text, matchCount, pmatch, 0 )) != 0 )
  {
    /**
     * regexec call failed.  There are a number of error codes that can be 
     * returned (text didn't match, pattern is invalid, etc.).  Check 
     * the documentation for regexec.
     */
    fprintf( stdout, "%s does not match %s, return code %d\n", text, ptn, ret );
  }
  else
  {
    /**
     * regexec call succeeded - print out all the matching expressions.
     */
    fprintf( stdout, "%s matches %s\n", text, ptn );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < matchCount; i++ )
    {
      if ( pmatch[i].rm_so >= 0 )
      {
        fprintf( stdout, "match %zu (start: %3lu; end: %3lu): %*.*s\n", i,
          (unsigned long) pmatch[i].rm_so,
          (unsigned long) pmatch[i].rm_eo,
          (int) ( pmatch[i].rm_eo - pmatch[i].rm_so ), 
          (int) ( pmatch[i].rm_eo - pmatch[i].rm_so ), 
          text + pmatch[i].rm_so );
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And, a sample run:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/regex: ./myregex
number of subexpressions: 8
<![LOG["The text to display in the log."]LOG]!><time="12:48:39.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="0" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp"> matches <!\[LOG\["(.*)"\]LOG\]!><time="(.*)" *date="(.*)" *component="(.*)" *context="(.*)" *type="(.*)" *thread="(.*)" *file="(.*)">
match 0 (start:   0; end: 160): <![LOG["The text to display in the log."]LOG]!><time="12:48:39.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="0" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">
match 1 (start:   8; end:  39): The text to display in the log.
match 2 (start:  54; end:  68): 12:48:39.0+120
match 3 (start:  76; end:  85): 9-14-2015
match 4 (start:  98; end: 109): mycomponent
match 5 (start: 120; end: 120):
match 6 (start: 128; end: 129): 0
match 7 (start: 139; end: 140): 0
match 8 (start: 148; end: 158): myfile.cpp
```

Remember that each `pmatch` entry only points into the source string; they are not separate strings themselves.

This is an *ideal* task for a regular expression library, whether it's POSIX regex or something else.  Hand-hacking your own parsing routines is certainly worthwhile as a learning experience, but if you don't *need* to do so, take advantage of the work other people have done.

Answer (score 2):

Search for `"` in pairs
start " --> end "  repeat.
example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    const char *text = "<![LOG[\"The text to display in the log.\"]LOG]!><time=\"12:48:39.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponent\" context=\"\" type=\"0\" thread=\"0\" file=\"myfile.cpp\">";

    const char *start = text;
    const char *end;
    while(start = strchr(start, '"')){
        ++start;
        end = strchr(start, '"');//if(end == NULL) bad format
        size_t len = end - start;
        char *pickup = malloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(pickup, start, len);
        pickup[len] = '\0';
        if(len)
            puts(pickup);
        else
            puts("\"\"");//empty
        free(pickup);
        start = end + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is fairly easy...

**EDIT :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
FILE *input;

fopen_s(&input,"myfile.cpp","r");

char c;

int printState = 0 , startPrinting = 0 ;

bool empty = true;

while( (c=getc(input)) != EOF )
{
    if( c == '"' )
        printState++;

    if( printState == 2 )
    {
        if( empty == true )
        {
            printf("\"\" (empty)\n");

            printState = 0;

            startPrinting = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");

            printState = 0;

            startPrinting = 0;

            empty = true;

        }
    }

    if( startPrinting == 1 )
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        empty = false;
    }

    if( printState == 1 )
    {
        startPrinting = 1;
    }

}

fclose(input);

return 0;
}
```